# Перевод записей в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, перевод

Здравствуйте.

Есть у меня БД, в ней регионы и города США. Но беда в том, что они на русском.

Задача: брать из базы названия по одному, например "Вашингтон", и перезаписывать в виде "Washington".

Решение 1 - брать всё ручками, и делать (долго и нудно, их там мильёны)
Решение 2 - написать какой-то скрипт, который это сделает

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку, только не издевайтесь над моим горем.

Answer (score 3):

- Если регионы никак не пополняются и используются только для связей,
  тогда перевести их нужно один раз, значит выгоднее сделать все
  ручками через любой переводчик.
- В обратном случае это означает, что БД пополняемая, тогда, перед
  записью лучше делать запрос к API переводчика и только потом уже
  сохранять, причем, могу предложить такую структуру:

regions:

```
+-------+-------+
|  id   |  ...  |
+-------+-------+
|   1   |  ...  |
+-------+-------+
|   2   |  ...  |
+-------+-------+
```

region_translations:

```
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  id   | region_id | lang |    name     |
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
|   1   |     1     |  ru  |  Вашингтон  |
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
|   2   |     1     |  en  |  Washington |
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
|   3   |     2     |  ru  |     ...     |
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
|   4   |     2     |  en  |     ...     |
+-------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Нет, не пополняемая, но их там мильён! Выгрузил базу в текст, сунул в google.translate, переводит чёрте-как. Хотя по одному если вставлять, то нормально переводит. А когда все города толпой - считает единым текстом, и пытается сделать дословно.

Comment: Попробуй выбрать их в csv или иной формат, чтобы они были с символом переноса строки и потом вставляй сразу столбиком.

Comment: Спасибо, выгрузил в .xsl, перевёл, всё нормально))  Теперь осталось вгрузить всё это обратно, но думаю, справлюсь)

Answer (score 2):

- Выгрузить таблицу в текстовой файл
- Воспользоваться [каким-нибудь](http://translit.net/) онлайн-транслитератором
- Загрузить обратно

Comment: транслитерация не совсем то, мне кажется, например Ваш предложенный транслитератор перевёл Айова, как Ajova. Но возможно, гугл транслейт сделает лучше. Пойду попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: Я привел первый попавшийся. А так да - выбирать нужно.